# Is it possible to find the host name (Computer name) in my LAN network if I know its IP address?

Tags: networking, lan, ip, hostname, nmap

I want to know whether this can be achieved using terminal. I have tried nmap, nslookup and netstat, and failed.

Comment: `nslookup <ip>` should work, tested with two ubuntu systems on the same lan

Comment: If something failed, what was / were the error message(s)?

Comment: The error i received while used nslookup was

** server can't find x.x.x.x.in-addr.arpa: NXDOMAIN

Comment: @[Sylvain Pineau](http://askubuntu.com/users/32239/sylvain-pineau) Can you please post your output here?